# Insert/Update operation locks the read operation in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

We are using arangodb 2.6.2.

Lets say there are 2 collection A and B.

`FOR a in A 
     INSERT {'x':1} in B`

When the above aql is running, my following query block:

```
FOR b in B return b
```

How can I avoid the locking of read while modifying in separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing without locking is unfortunately not possible at the moment.

As we started 3 years ago to build Arango we made the design decision to work with collection locks at the beginning.

This decision has made some things easier - but it hurts especially with long running queries as in your example.

But it is planned to change this when we reach some milestones. 3.0 was the most important of them and we will target the locking stuff now.

We will hopefully finish the development for this later this year.

Comment: Conceptually, there are two types of locks: read locks and write locks. If a collection is locked for writing, it can not be locked for reading by another query. Internally, there is a counter, which is increased by 1 by every reader and decreased by 1 when it's done reading. A write lock can only be acquired if this counter is 0, so no one is reading anymore. Concurrent reading is possible nonetheless.